# Image of function: extracting points with python

Tags: python, image

Suppose that I have an image like this one:

[image]

I would like to get a list of the points (x,y) that compose the line. Is there a way of doing this in Python? If I load the image as a matrix I would get some elements of the matrix indicating that there is "black". The problem is that the line might have some width, and so there would be many matrix elements corresponding to the same point on the line. How can I fix this? Is there a straightforward way of doing what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHAT do you mean with "the same point on the line"? Which of the "points" would be the right one if the thickness of a (horizontal/vertical) line is 2 or 4 pixels (even number, so there is no "middle" one)? And if the thickness is one pixel - what do you consider as "connected"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a complicated problem.  You need to extract all of the points in the image that are black, then find a way to condense them to a more limited set of data that roughly traces the path.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io
from sklearn.cluster import mean_shift

# get the image
url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKAk5.png'
res = requests.get(url)
# set the content as a file pointer object
fp = io.BytesIO(res.content)
# load the image to PIL
img = Image.open(fp)

# convert the image to gray-scale and load it to a numpy array
# need to transpose because the X and Y are swapped in PIL
# need [:,::-1] because pngs are indexed from the upper left
arr = np.array(img.convert('L')).T[:,::-1]
# get indices where there line is the pixel values is dark, ie <100
indices = np.argwhere(arr < 100)
```

So far we have the indices, or the (x,y) locations, where a dark pixel occurs. But there are way more of those than you need.  To reduce the number, we can use a clustering technique to reduce the number of points.  The `mean_shift` clustering technique is appropriate here.  It assigns a kernel to a set of points, then iteratively lets the points nearby slowly pull together.  The main parameter is the bandwidth of the kernel, which is how 'wide' the pull is.

```
# this shows how many clusters are formed per bandwidth
for x in np.arange(.5,5.6,.25):
    print('{:.2f}: '.format(x), end='')
    print(len(mean_shift(indices, bandwidth=x)[0]))

# returns:
0.50: 1697
0.75: 1697
1.00: 539
1.25: 397
1.50: 364
1.75: 343
2.00: 277
2.25: 247
2.50: 232
2.75: 221
3.00: 194
3.25: 175
3.50: 165
3.75: 160
4.00: 156
4.25: 138
4.50: 139
4.75: 133
5.00: 120
5.25: 111
5.50: 112
```

So for a ~200 point approximation of the line you can use a bandwidth of 3.0.

```
points, labels = mean_shift(indices, bandwidth=3.0)

# lets plot the points
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks m8, I definitely was aware of the difficulty, but was hoping to find any module that implemented this. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

you can use opencv for this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('squiggly.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, image = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

scatter = np.where(image==0)
x,y = scatter[1],-scatter[0]

plt.scatter(x,y,color='blue',marker='.',s=0.2)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This however produces plenty of points, doesn't it?